# is there a way to skip rows within lapply to automate a task?

Tags: r

How can I use an R function to automate something like this? I understand how to do it if row1 and row2 were one digit apart but the only way I can think of to skip values like this is to use a global variable (despite the fact that the offset is exactly 5 each time). Can someone suggest a better method? This is only a snippet, I have to perform this task almost 2000 times

```
cond<-rbind(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(9,9,9),c(9,9,9),c(9,9,9),c(9,9,9),c(7,8,9))
row1<-rbind(cond[c(1,2),])
avatar10<-matrix(colMeans(row1), ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
row2<-rbind(cond[c(6,7),])
avatar20<-matrix(colMeans(row2), ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)
result<-rbind(avatar10,avatar20)
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you're trying to get the column-wise averages of rows, 1+2, 6+7, 11+12, 16+17, and so on?

Comment: By the way, `rbind` on a single argument like `rbind(cond[c(1,2),])` is rarely necessary. It just turns it into a matrix, which it already is in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the indices you want to apply it to with `seq`, using a `step` argument of 5. Then you can use `sapply` to perform your `colMeans` operation on each. In your case:

```
# example 10000 by 3 matrix
cond <- replicate(3, rnorm(10000))

indices <- seq(1, nrow(cond), 5)
result <- t(sapply(indices, function(i) colMeans(cond[i:(i + 1), ])))
```

(Notice that you had to transpose it afterwards since `sapply` stores each result as a column of a matrix, while you want each result as a row).

In the case of the specific problem you're solving, there's an even easier (and more computationally efficient) solution:

```
result <- (cond[indices, ] + cond[indices + 1, ]) / 2
```

However, this may not extend to more complex problems (e.g. if you're averaging more than two rows).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowsum`.

Here's an example, just to make sure we're talking about the same thing:

```
set.seed(1)
n    <- 5
nr   <- 50
dat  <- replicate(3, rnorm(nr))
idx  <- sapply(seq(1, nr-1, by=n), `+`, 0:1)

idx 

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16   21   26   31   36   41    46
# [2,]    2    7   12   17   22   27   32   37   42    47
```

So, you want to col-mean rows 1&2, 6&7, 11&12 and so on.

```
res = rowsum(dat[c(idx),], c(col(idx))) / nrow(idx)

#           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
# 1  -0.22140524 -0.10696026 -0.2891254
# 2  -0.16651967  0.80658921  1.2419974
# 3   0.95081220  1.18118888 -0.5486906
# 4  -0.03056194 -0.80808316 -0.3564004
# 5   0.85055684 -0.11721845  0.4185407
# 6  -0.10596212 -0.07592282  0.3195510
# 7   0.62794591 -0.35192367 -0.2643670
# 8  -0.40464226  0.69802510 -0.9187130
# 9  -0.20894264  0.33267389 -0.3688881
# 10 -0.17145660 -0.35905289  0.6681738

# for comparison, the first row computed manually
colMeans(dat[c(1,2),])

# [1] -0.2214052 -0.1069603 -0.2891254
```

`rowsum` is a really weird name for this, but it's all explained in the docs, at `?rowsum`.